# MySQL - connecting two ids in one table

Tags: mysql

This query is something about connecting between two ids in just one table.

Table: employer

```
Employee no.  Lastname  Firstname  reports to  title
111           Garret    Mike       333         sales manager
333           Frank     Savage     444         President
```

My question is how do I connect this table?

The table should be like:

```
Employee no.  Lastname  Firstname  reports to(Supervisor No.)  Firstname   Lastame
111           Garret    Mike       333                         Frank       Savage
```

I tried:

```
Select Employee no., Lastname, Firstname, reports to AS SuperVisorNumber, firstname, lastname From Employer
Where Employer.reports to =Employeeno.reports to
```

This is just an example. Don't worry about the misspelling and everything.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what your looking to do as well as correct the errors, format AND include full code for it to be possible to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to join the table to itself:

```
select e1.Employeeno,
  e1.lastname EmpLastName,
  e1.firstname empFirstName,
  e1.reportsto,
  e2.firstname MgrFirstName,
  e2.lastname MgrLastName
from employer e1
inner join employer e2
  on e1.reportsto = e2.employeeno
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b388f/3)

If you want to see all employees, including the president, then change it to a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select e1.Employeeno,
  e1.lastname EmpLastName,
  e1.firstname empFirstName,
  e1.reportsto,
  e2.firstname MgrFirstName,
  e2.lastname MgrLastName
from employer e1
left join employer e2
  on e1.reportsto = e2.employeeno
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b388f/2)

If, you want to use more descriptive table aliases, then you can use something like this:

```
from employer employee
left join employer manager
  on employee.reportsto = manager.employeeno
```

Comment: Just a question. What is e1. and e2. ?

Comment: @LinearXCon those are aliases for the table, you can call them whatever you want.  But since you are doing a self-join, the names need to be distinct

Comment: I'm a complete noob on this mysql. How do you rewrite 
e1.Employeeno as?